# Delete all subscribers from a list

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to remove all subscribes from a list and every list their in. I know this can be done in the UI. looking at the API but not sure how to delete the all subscribers from all list not just the one in question.

Any help appreciated
Pete

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar of how the subscribers are stored and how are they linked to a certain list so I will make the following assumtions:

Considering all the Subscriber information is in the `Subscriber__c` SObject, and all the list information is int the `List__c` SObject, where the `List__c` is the master detail object in the List -> Subscriber relationship called `Subscribers`.

Then I would perfrom the following queries to get all the Subscribers which are related to all the lists and then delete them.

```
Set<Id> subscriberIds = new Set<ID>();
List<List__c> alllists= new List<List__c>([Select id, (Select id from Subscribers) from List__c]);

for(List_c l: alllists)
{
   for(Subscriber__c s : l.Subscribers)
  {

   subscriberids.add(s.id);
  }
}

List<Subscriber__c> allrelatedsubscribers = new List<Subscriber__c>([Select id from Subscriber__c where id in: subscriberids)]


delete allrelatedsubscribers;
```

This code should give you a good starting point in understanding what you have to do in order to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: This is a SF Marketing Cloud question, not a Sales Cloud question.